# How to get these results in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to fix a problem I have, but I can't get the answers right.

```
"""
Given is the following heading of a function to calculate the cosines.

               def cosines (x, number_of_terms):
               # x is a float; number_of_terms is an int

This method calculates the cosines of x with the series

    x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + x^9/9! - ...


x^n is the notation for "x to the power n" and n! is the notation for "the factorial of n".
The number of terms that should be calculated is given by the parameter number_of_terms.
Implement this method.

Do this without using any functions from the module math. Assume: number_of_terms >= 1.
"""
```

So, what I did is this:

```
def cosines(x, number_of_terms):
    sign = 1
    result = 0.0
    counter = x
    denominator = 1.0

    for i in range (number_of_terms, number_of_terms+1):
        fracture = counter / denominator
        term = sign * fracture
        result += term
        counter *= x 
        denominator *= i
        sign = - sign
    return result

first = cosines(90.0, 1)
second = cosines(90.0, 4)
third = cosines(90.0, 8)

print "should be 30.000000: %f" % first
print "should be -4546255.714286: %f" % second
print "should be -7167780281079.437000: %f" % third
```

This is the result I get:

```
---BEGIN TEST---
should be 30.000000: 90.000000
should be -4546255.714286: 90.000000
should be -7167780281079.437000: 90.000000
----END TEST----
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The expansion you see here works with *radians*, not *degrees*.

Comment: Furthermore your bounds don't make much sense, since both `sin` and `cos` have a range of `[-1,1]`.

Comment: Your power series is for Sine and not Cosine.  The Macluarin theorem applied to Cosine produces this power series: cos(x) = 1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - x^6/6! + x^8/8! - ...

Comment: If you look at the series, you can see that you only need a new term if i has increased by 2 ...

Comment: I really don't get anything you said, guys. Sorry, am new to Python and this is all I can do for now. That's why I asked for help.

Comment: @PeterPesch: I tried doing i*2, but that didn't give me the correct output.

Comment: @Siyah you have to look in steps of 2. For instance `(1,3,5,7,9)`. You are doing something like `(8,9)`.

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't start with 8 or so? Ah, I am just confused now. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Siyah You start with `number of terms` and end with `number of terms+1`. That way you get a series consisting of only 2 terms. Your series should start with the term `x` (or 1, if you want the cosinus rather than the sinus). Furthermore, it makes no sense taking 90 as an example value for this function. It would make sense if your x were an angle in degrees. For your formula, x should be an angle in radians ...

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code and changed the names of the function to 'sines' as that is what the math reflects:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)   

def sines(x_in_degrees, number_of_terms):
    # Convert to radians
    #import math
    #x = math.radians(x_in_degrees)
    x = x_in_degrees * 3.141592653589793/180.0

    sign = 1
    result = 0.0
    p = 1

    for i in range(1, number_of_terms+1):
        num = x**p 
        denom = factorial(p)
        temp = sign * num / denom
        #temp = sign * math.pow(x, p) / math.factorial(p)

        result = result + temp 
        sign = - sign
        p = p + 2
    return result

first = sines(90.0, 1)
second = sines(90.0, 4)
third = sines(90.0, 8)

print "Result with one term: %f" % first
print "Result with four terms: %f" % second
print "Result with eight terms: %f" % third
```

Comment: @paisanco Thanks for that detail.  I totally missed it.  I made changes.

Answer (score 0):

(EDITED) As pointed out in the comments, your code needs to

1. Work with angles in radians, not degrees
2. Implement the correct power series for cosine

Interpreting "number of terms" as the number of relevant terms in the power series you want computed, below is an example computing the cosine of 45 degrees or pi/4 radians.

If you want to compute the factorial in the loop, the key to making the code work is that that the computation of a term is done only for even iterations, to match the cosine power series.

```
def cosines(x, number_of_terms):
    sign = 1
    result = 1
    counter = x
    denominator = 1.0
    # Counting the 1 in the cosine power series as the first "term"
    terms_computed = 1
    # skip computing for iterations not relevant to the power series
    iterations = 1
    while terms_computed < number_of_terms:
        iterations += 1
        counter *= x 
        denominator *= iterations
        if iterations %2 == 0:
            terms_computed += 1
            sign = - sign
            fracture = counter / denominator
            term = sign * fracture
            result += term


    print 'input %d, number of relevant terms computed %d'%(number_of_terms,terms_computed)
    return result

pi= 3.1415926
angle = pi/4.
print 'angle in radians ',angle
first = cosines(angle, 1)
second = cosines(angle, 2)
third = cosines(angle, 4)
fourth = cosines(angle, 8)
fifth = cosines(angle, 10)

print "first %f" % first
print "second %f" % second
print "third %f" % third
print "fourth %f" % fourth
print "fifth %f" % fifth
```

Results:

angle in radians  0.78539815

input 1, number of relevant terms computed 1

input 2, number of relevant terms computed 2

input 4, number of relevant terms computed 4

input 8, number of relevant terms computed 8

input 10, number of relevant terms computed 10

first 1.000000
second 0.691575
third 0.707103
fourth 0.707107
fifth 0.707107

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the meaning of "number of terms". If your function is called with `number_of_terms` = 1, your function returns a result based on 2 terms. If your function is called with `number_of_terms` = 10, your function returns a result based on 6 terms ...

Comment: Edited code. I interpreted "number of terms" to mean number of relevant terms desired in the power series, to include the first term (1).